# How to convert date as 'Monday 1st' to'Monday 1' in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have tried a lot. Banning words doesn't help, removing certain characters doesn't help.

The datetime module doesn't have a directive for this. It has things like `%d` which will give you today's day, for example `24`.

I have a date in the format of '`Tuesday 24th January`' but I need it to be '`Tuesday 24 January`'.

Is there a way to remove `st`,`nd`,`rd`,`th`. Or is there an even better way?

EDIT: even removing `rd` would remove it from Saturday. So that doesn't work either.

Comment: regex `(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)` and output only 1st group.

Comment: regex is probably the way to go, but if you want something using just strings in python, you can use the knowledge that the numbers are always the middle word of the date - so something like `x = my_date.split(' ')` and then `output = f'{x[0]} {x[1][:-2]} {x[2]}'` would work as well

Comment: "even removing rd would remove it from Saturday." Did you try approaches that **look for** the number, and remove the `rd` *from after it*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

d = 'Tuesday 24th January'
d = re.sub(r'(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)', r'\1', d)  # \1 to restore the captured day
print(d)

# Output
Tuesday 24 January
```

For Saturday 21st January:

```
d = 'Saturday 21st January'
d = re.sub(r'(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)', r'\1', d)
print(d)

# Output
Saturday 21 January
```

Comment: Check this link: https://regex101.com/r/QMrZ1f/1 . It's an explanation for the regex. You can train with it.

Comment: [This](http://pinkpawmovement.com/2023/01/24/how-to-convert-date-as-monday-1st-to-monday-1-in-python/) might help.

Comment: Nice! You do need to make the second group a capturing group. I mean you can do it as https://regex101.com/r/Cs9eUh/1.

Comment: @Beginner. You are right, we don't need to capture the suffix.